# Is there any way to make "Crystal Reports " responsive for mobile browser

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, crystal-reports

I am Making my whole Asp.net App Responsive for the mobile browser using Bootstrap. but I am unable to make Crystal Report Responsive for the mobile browser. Is there Any way to make Crystal report responsive for mobile browsers, Please Share advice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

well I would guess you need to use `width: 100vw; height: auto;` on any of the container divs and also navigation bar containers.